# First item in gridview not showing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am creating a chess app and my board gets drawn but the first square with the black Rook doesn't appear until after the first move. I will attach pictures below as well as my xml code and my code for the adapter which creates the gridView. But does anyone have any idea as to why the first square won't show. I'm assuming it is because my view has no size until my getView method is invoked but I do not know how to fix that. If someone could please explain how to fix this, that'd be awesome.

[Board Before First Move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR2Mr.png)

[Board After First Move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w2rl.png)

Adapter Code:

```
public class SquareAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Piece[][] board;

    public SquareAdapter(Context context, Piece[][] board) {
        this.context = context;
        this.board = board;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 64;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ImageView view;
        if (convertView == null)
        {

            view = new ImageView(context);
            int size = parent.getWidth()/8;

            view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size,size));

            int col = position/8 %2;

            if (col == 0)
            {
                if (position%2 == 0)
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DFAE74"));
                else
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6B4226"));
            }
            else
            {
                if (position%2 == 0)
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6B4226"));
                else
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DFAE74"));
            }

            Piece p = board[position/8][position%8];

            if(p!= null)
            {
                if(p.isWhite)
                {
                    view.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("w"+p.type, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
                }
                else if(!p.isWhite)
                {
                    view.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("b"+p.type, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            view = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartGameActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resignButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="@string/resign"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drawButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:text="@string/draw"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridViewBoard"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameText"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/game_text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/resignButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/drawButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aiButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ai"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/undoButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="@string/undo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewBoard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:columnWidth="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/drawButton" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: I apologize. But no one was answering :(